# How is bad hand writing treated in the Japanese culture

Tags: words

How bad can your hiragana, katakana and kanji characters be before people start to complain about it. I know a fair bit of Arabic, Spanish, and English, and in all of those languages and their respective cultures, it is fairly normal for people to have very bad had writing.

Comment: "How bad" is a little vague way to ask because it's mainly opinion-based, and it's hard to have a comparison of "badness" between different scripts if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Shodo (書道, calligraphy) defines how those glyphs can be broken. At least "beautiful" broken glyphs has some rules, so when correctly written "行書" and "草書" are always readable. Broken glyphs out of such rules aren't guaranteed to be understood. This would be common for all Kanji-based cultures I suppose.